# PHP __CLASS__ like magic constant respect inheritance?

Tags: php, class, reflection

Is there a magic constant which, when used in a parent class, will return its child's class name, and not the parent?

Comment: `static::class` works in PHP >=5.5, or `get_called_class()` in PHP >=5.3.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a constant only. But using `get_class($this);` in parent you will get the class of the caller(parent or child)